# elastic_transport.ConnectionTimeout: Connection timeout caused by: ConnectionError

Tags: python, elasticsearch, connection-timeout, langchain

I have a rather simplistic program that consists of adding items to an elasticsearch server in python :

```
dir = DATA_DIR
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=settings_app.OPENAI_API_KEY)
db = ElasticVectorSearch(
        elasticsearch_url=settings_app.ELASTICSEARCH_URL,
        index_name=settings_app.ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX,
        embedding=embeddings,
    )    

loader = DirectoryLoader(dir, glob="**/*.pdf", loader_cls=PyPDFLoader)
documents = loader.load()

# Split the loaded PDF files into smaller text pieces for easier processing
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=0)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

db.add_documents(texts)
```

The Elastic VectorSearch class is provided by the langchain library.
When I run this program, I get the following error:

```
elastic_transport.ConnectionTimeout: Connection timeout caused by: ConnectionError(Connection error caused by: ProtocolError(('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))))
```

My index already exists and is accessible, since I've tried adding some data to it using another method. The problem is that I have to use this langchain function because I have a chatbot running on it. The elasticsearch server is on the network of the company where I work and not on localhost.

Comment: have same issue, have you solved it yet ? which es version you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass bulk arguments when adding documents, which helps prevent timeouts when ingesting a large number of documents.

*bulk_kwargs – Additional arguments to pass to Elasticsearch bulk.

- [chunk_size](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/vectorstores/langchain.vectorstores.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStore.html#langchain.vectorstores.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStore.add_texts): Optional. Number of texts to add to the index at a time. Defaults to 500.

  ```
    vector_store.add_texts(
    texts,
    bulk_kwargs={
        "chunk_size": 50,
        "max_chunk_bytes": 200000000
    })
  ```

For more details, please refer to the [documentation](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/elasticsearch#question-im-getting-timeout-errors-when-indexing-documents-into-elasticsearch-how-do-i-fix-this) for guidance on using this feature.